# How to achieve something like below using arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create n number of arrays using for loop in Java script, How do i achieve it ?

I have tried to do it but couldn't get the results what i wanted, Please refer the below code.

```
function createMultipleArray() {
  var array = [];
  var large_array = [];
  var sample = 'Sample'

  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    array.push([sample + "," + 'arr' + i]);
    large_array.push(array);
  }
  console.log(large_array);
}
```

Expected Output:

```
        ['sample', 'arr1'],
        ['sample', 'arr2'],
        ['sample', 'arr3'],
        ['sample', 'arr4'],
        ['sample', 'arr5'],

        ['arr1', 'arr1_Subarr1'],
        ['arr1', 'arr1_Subarr2'],
        ['arr1', 'arr1_Subarr3'],
        ['arr1', 'arr1_Subarr4'],
        ['arr1', 'arr1_Subarr5'],

        ['arr2', 'arr2_Subarr1'],
        ['arr2', 'arr2_Subarr2'],
        ['arr2', 'arr2_Subarr3'],
        ['arr2', 'arr2_Subarr4'],
        ['arr2', 'arr2_Subarr5'],

        ['arr3', 'arr3_Subarr1'],
        ['arr3', 'arr3_Subarr2'],
        ['arr3', 'arr3_Subarr3'],
        ['arr3', 'arr3_Subarr4'],
        ['arr3', 'arr3_Subarr5']
```

Comment: between your output being invalid syntax and your code not really reflecting what you _do_ show as output, i can't tell what exactly you're going for. Can you you clarify?

Comment: What is the specification of `*_Subarr `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
array.push([sample + "," + 'arr' + i])
```

you're creating an array with one element, which is a string concatenating all those parts. You shouldn't concatenate the comma, you should use that as a delimiter between the array elements.

```
array.push([sample, 'arr' + i]);
```

But you shouldn't use the same `array` variable each time through the loop. Each time you do that, you're extending the same array, and then adding another reference to that array to the `large_array`. You only need to push onto `large_array`.\

To get different names instead of `Sample` and `arr`, you can make those parameters to the function.

```js
function createMultipleArray(sample, prefix) {
  var large_array = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    large_array.push([sample, prefix + i]);
  }
  return large_array;
}
console.log(createMultipleArray('Sample', 'arr'));
console.log(createMultipleArray('arr1', 'arr1_Subarr'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar for taking your time in explaining clearly, I have understood it now.